# Plotly comppatibility issue with IE 11

Tags: r, d3.js, internet-explorer-11, plotly

I wonder if plotly has any compatibility issues with IE11. I have tried the following code and I can see the hoverinfo from the viewer in RStudio. However, if I open it in IE11, the hoverinfo becomes blank.

```
df = data.frame(a='High',
                info="this text doesn't mean anything and it's only here as a demonstration. You can replace this with anything else
                and I want to somehow wrap this text",
                start=as.Date("31/12/2015","%d/%m/%Y"),
                end = as.Date("31/12/2016","%d/%m/%Y"))
p = plot_ly()

p <- add_trace(p,
                 x = c(df$start[1], df$end[1]),  # x0, x1
                 y = c(1,1),  # y0, y1
                 mode = "lines",
                 line = list(color ="#FF6600", width = 20),
                 showlegend = F,
                 hoverinfo = "text",
                 text = gsub('\\.','.<br>',df$info[1]),
                 evaluate = T
                 #hoverinfo = "value"
)
p
```

RStudio Viewer:
[image]

IE11:
[image]